# Can we use JBoss EAP 6.4 to develop/deploy Portal application and SOA application?

Tags: jboss, version, portlet, soa

Can we use  JBoss EAP 6.4 to develop/deploy  Portal application and SOA application ?  We want to use Jboss ESB and portlets in same application server.

Do we require any other packages or eap would be sufficient?
  Does JBOSS EAP 6.4 is compatible with which  Application server of JBOSS ?

May i know which application server of JBOSS is compatible with  JBOSS EAP 64. ?